# select title, left (description, 50), due, assigned_to, completed, priority FROM tasks

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull values from a table and i'm requesting that description be truncated at 50 chars or less. I cant figure out why it is failing.

```
$tomorrow = "select title, left (description, 50), due, assigned_to, completed, priority FROM tasks WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(due)) = curdate()";

 <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title"><?=$today['title'];?></h4>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><?=$today['due'];?></h6>
    <p class="card-text">
       <?=$today['description']; ?>
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Complete</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
</div>
```

I get this error: "Notice: Undefined index: description"

It works when i change the query to this:

```
select title, description, due, assigned_to, completed, priority FROM tasks WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(due)) = curdate();
```

Comment: Maybe change the title of the question to an explanation of your problem instead of your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is coming from here:

```
$today['description']
```

Make sure that `$today` has an index named `description` and you should be good.

Comment: thanks! i did a var_dump on $today and it gave me an index for description as 'left (description, 50)'

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Ray O'Donnell for pointing me in the right direction. here is what i did:

```
var_dump($today);
```

the dump revealed the index name for description as:

```
'left (description, 50)'
```

i replaced that in my output:

```
$today['left (description, 50)'];
```

there must be a more intuitive way to do this.